# Who pays for employer health insurance coverage in Germany?

Tags: germany, health-insurance

I am not sure if the contract (photo attached) includes that the health insurance is to be paid by employer or employee in Germany.
[image: germany]
Previously I worked in Italy and the employer paid my health insurance.

Comment: In Germany, health insurance is paid by both, one part employer and one part employee. So not sure what exactly you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the way this works is that working (or residing) in Germany entails paying into several mandatory insurance systems. There are some very limited exemptions and what the excerpt you shared means is that your contract does not qualify for one of these exemptions.

You will therefore have to get all the insurances listed in the contract (namely retirement, healthcare, unemployment, and accident). I think it also means that you are eligible to join the statutory health insurance system, i.e. you don't have to take a private insurance if you don't want to. Beyond that the system is quite complicated, exactly who pays what and how much depends on how high your salary is and on a couple of choices you have to make yourself (private or statutory, which “Kasse” you join).

My guess is that you should expect to pay at least a few hundreds of euros a month out of your salary, which isn't the full cost because your employer will also cover some of it. But I am not fully up-to-date on the details of the system and you haven't disclosed all relevant details. If you want to know more, you should probably ask a follow-up question.

Comment: Generaly the employer pays 50% of the rate of the health provider. If that rate is 15.8%, then the employer pays 7.9% and the employee also 7.9%.